# Using PHP to bring info in another page

Tags: php

Sorry very new to coding in general and I want to create a very basic site which will have a top banner and a navigation bar and a table underneath the bar which will hold the information. I want the nav bar links to load in the table without going to a seperate file. So what I have is an index.php which consists of this.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BHSC TORONTO</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<?php include ('banner.php'); ?>
<?php include ('navbar.php'); ?>
<br />
<center>
<table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>All information would go here when link is clicked.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
<br />
<center><iframe width="900" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/144156578&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_artwork=true"></iframe></center>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is for the links to load the pages into the table index.php instead of linking to seperate pages that would require to be fully designed. Sorry I looked around but couldn't find this exact information. Googled and youtubed as well... I maybe searching for the wrong term. Again very new to PHP.

Comment: You need JavaScript for that.

Comment: If it has to be done without page refresh then look for AJAX In google. Otherwise this page can be made dynamic which shows content based on url parameters.

Comment: I'm going to look on google and read up AJAX information but I don't think it is what I was looking for however I really appreciate your reply. @Hanky웃Panky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let, u have two pages home.php and another.php

your links of navbar should be like
`<a href="index.php?pg=1">Home</a>`

```
<a href="index.php?pg=2">Another</a>
```

then in your index.php

```
<td> <?php 
if($_REQUEST['pg']==1)
include('home.php');
elseif($_REQUEST['pg']==2)
include('another.php');

?> </td>
```

that's set

Comment: Yes I believe it is something I saw achievable with PHP which is why I did not stray to look further then PHP coding. I don't know much about Javascript. So can this code you provided only work with two pages or if I wanted to continue with more variables in the if commands? pg 3 pg 4 etc?